# Scroll should not go to the bottom while data change

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

In My angularJs application, I have a problem with scroll bar. There is a pop up which show a list of data in it and I refresh that data after every 5 seconds, by calling my API service in every 5 seconds.

Problem is that after refresh, side scroll bar goes automatically to the bottom. I google for that but dn't get satisfied solution, I  used $anchorScroll in my config file which is not help full as well.

I am using Angular Material's md-dialog-content for popup list.

```
<md-dialog-content>
        <div layout="row">
              <div class="simple-table-container" flex>

                <table class="simple" ms-responsive-table>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>ProcessItem</th>
                      <th>ElapsedTime</th>
                      <th>Status</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>

                  <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tfoot>

                  <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="info in vm.process.data">
                      <td>{{info.item}}</td>
                      <td>{{info.time}}</td>
                      <td>{{info.Status}}</td>
                    </tr>

                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
```

```
vm.process.processInterval = $interval(function () {
        api.getdata.get({ 'ID': id },
            function (response) {
                if (response.data[0].hdata[0].pdata)
                    vm.process.data = response.data[0].hdata[0].pdata;

                $scope.$watch(
                    "vm.process.data",
                    function (newObj, oldObj) {
                        if (newObj !== oldObj) {
                            vm.process.data = newObj;
                        }
                    }, true
                );
            },

            function (response) {
                console.error(response);
            }
        );
    }, 5000);
```

Any Idea guys?

Comment: Please include the **relevant** code and html for this

Comment: @devqon code included

Answer (score 0):

As I understand after ajax update page your scroll position not change. This is normal situation and in this case you should manual trigger scroll top to element that you want: `element.scrollTop = pixels`.

In other case you have some hash in url that trigger scroll to bottom element. And in this case you should clear it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But I want that my scroll position should not change, after data updated. There is not hash in my url.

Comment: can you create some jsbin demo with mock data, cause as I understand all should works well.